# SSMS 2008 queries execution timeout does not allow changing anything

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, timeout, ssms

SSMS 2008 with a local database.

1. I can't rename any column of any table. It says: **Unable to rename column from ... to ... Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.**
2. I tried to rename the column using **sp_RENAME** procedure. No result. It just keeps trying, the progress icon moves but it takes infinite time.
3. I tried to truncate the table, but again, the query starts and never finishes.
4. I can change rows and values manually if I open a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restart your SQL Server Instance.

Comment: One reason should be memory pressure on sql server.